# Background image of list element won't show in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have a simple list with a background image in each element. The image is showing in Firefox but no in Chrome (Windows OS). These are the styles attached to the list:

```
ul li
{
  position: relative;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-style: dotted;
  border-bottom-color: #777777;
  width: 378px;
  float: left;
  padding-top: 6px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
  color: #575656;
  line-height: 19px;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: url("../images/tir.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: scroll;
  background-position: left top 6px;
  background-clip: border-box;
  background-origin: padding-box;
  background-size: auto auto;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}
```

Can someone spot what's wrong with this?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kgeDr/

Comment: How about a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to demonstrate?

Comment: @TomWalters I've added a fiddle to my question. ... And it works in the fiddle. But there are no other styles applied to the list. I think. Back to the lab I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code seems to work.. http://jsfiddle.net/LZKG6/
(I use Chrome in Ubuntu)

May be this is wrong:

```
background-position: left top 6px;
```

I think the extra "6px" is invalid.

W3schools only specifies 2 values, not 3:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp

Comment: Yeah, removing that "6px" fixed the issue. Although it was working in Firefox, now the image is a little misaligned but I'll handle that in some other way.